# Zend 2 + Postgresql views - getGeneratedValue()

Tags: postgresql, insert, zend-framework2, lastinsertid

I'm using views in Postgresql and I encounter a problem in Zend: I can't retrieve the last inserted value of an insert request.

Example:
I have an user_view and when I insert in, it does instead:

```
INSERT INTO basic_user(name, email) VALUES [...]; INSERT INTO extended_user(id, phone) VALUES (lastval(), [...]);
```

When I execute the request in Zend and call getGeneratedValue() it returns NULL...

How can I get the lastval() ?

I tried to use the RETURNING clause in my INSERT but without success..

Thx for your help.

Comment: Problem solved.

Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039629/zend-database-last-id-of-inserted-row-using-postgres

Comment: You can also use this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/13862746/1742415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in PGSQL is `currval(Sequence name)` [PG Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html).

Example

> INSERT INTO basic_user(name, email) VALUES [...]; INSERT INTO extended_user(id, phone) VALUES (currval(basic_user_seq)(), [...]);